# jquery array to string

Tags: jquery, post

I am submitting the value of a form on click with jQuery Post function,
Form is like

```
<form id="event-save" class="horizontal-form" name="event-save" action="">

<input type="text" id='event_1' name="event_1" />

<input type="text" id='event_2' name="event_2" />

<input type="text" id='event_3' name="event_3" />

// building check boxes dynamically from database table

<input type="checkbox" value="xyz_1" name="event_type[]" /> 

<input type="checkbox" value="xyz_2" name="event_type[]" />

<input type="checkbox" value="xyz_2" name="event_type[]" />

<input type="checkbox" value="xyz_1" name="event_type[]" />

</form>
```

I am receiving the values of form element with jQuery like

```
  var SavingData = '';
  SavingData += '&event_1='+jQuery('#event_1').val();
  SavingData += '&event_2='+jQuery('#event_2').val();
  SavingData += '&event_3='+jQuery('#event_3').val();


  jQuery.post("ajax/save_event.php",SavingData, function(){
              jQuery('#update_message').css("display","block");
      });
```

My question is how to send the data of only checked check boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`$('form').serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/); only name/value pairs of checked checkboxes will be captured.

**DEMO**

```js
$('#check').on('click', function() {
  var SavingData = $('form').serialize();
  alert( SavingData );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="event-save" class="horizontal-form" name="event-save" action="">

<input type="text" id='event_1' name="event_1" />

<input type="text" id='event_2' name="event_2" />

<input type="text" id='event_3' name="event_3" />

<br>
  
<input type="checkbox" value="xyz_1" name="event_type[]" /> 

<input type="checkbox" value="xyz_2" name="event_type[]" />

<input type="checkbox" value="xyz_2" name="event_type[]" />

<input type="checkbox" value="xyz_1" name="event_type[]" />

</form>

<button id="check">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use jQuery's [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Example code, using [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'my/url.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('form').serialize(),    
    success: function (data) {...}
});
```